# External function with global variables

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I want to write functions in external files, as it is more convenient for edition, and use global variables.

Apparently the only way to do that is to use import some_function from some_file (right?). Is it possible to still use global variables in this way? That is variables declared in the main file and directly accessible in the external file? I also try to avoid passing them in arguments as it complicates the code. I was thinking about some "include" instruction but I'm not sure it exists in Python.

So the code in the main file would be this:

```
from test import test
x=1
test()
```

and in the file test.py it would be this:

```
def test():
    global x
    print(x)
```

Maybe this is just a problem of having the right editor...Has anyone a recommandation for MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

python's `import` is pretty much equivalent to `include` in other languages, especially in the form of `from some_file import *` which imports all of the namespace, including functions, classes, and all global variables in that module or package.

Edit: However, if you want to do what you requested in your comments, that can still be done with imported variables. Let's for example consider 2 files, `main.py` and `imported.py`.

`imported.py` might look like this:

```
some_global_var = 1
other_var = 2

def add():
    return some_global_var + other_var
```

Because `imported.py` has functions that use global variables (instead of arguments), there's no reason you can't change those variables once imported. To do that, `main.py` can look like this:

```
import imported

print(imported.add()) # 3 - because we didn't change anything yet
imported.some_global_var = 10
imported.other_var = 20
print(imported.add()) # 30 - because we redefined the imported variables that our imported function uses
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution where the global variables of the main file can be accessible in the external file.

Comment: @kaleidoscop added an edit to explain how this can be done

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm actually using those global variables in the main file, and in other external files, I just want them to be accessible in the external function. I added an example in the post.

Comment: @kaleidoscop I'm afraid the exact format you're after in your edit doesn't exist

Comment: Ok many thanks. What about putting "import main" in "test.py" and then call "main.x" in the file test.py? Does it make sense?

Comment: @kaleidoscop that would make more sense, yes, but that means that you have to run all your code logic in `test.py`

Comment: Ok I see. Then I guess "good practices" would be to pass everything as arguments, right?